# Maven plugins running out of order

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have two plugins that must run in order, but no matter how I specify them in the pom.xml, they run in the opposite order.  Here is the POM snippet, using Maven 3.3.1:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>ejbcompile</id>
         <phase>compile</phase>
         <configuration>
            <ejbVersion>2.0</ejbVersion>
            <generateClient>true</generateClient>
            <clientIncludes>
               <clientInclude>com/myproject/**/interfaces/**</clientInclude>
               <clientInclude>*.ser</clientInclude>
            </clientIncludes>
            <ejbJar>META-INF/ejb-jar.xml</ejbJar>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>wsejbdeploy</id>
         <phase>compile</phase>
         <configuration>
            <tasks>
               <path id="was.classpath">
                  <fileset dir="${my.washome}/plugins">
                     <include name="com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar" />
                  </fileset>
               </path>    
               <taskdef name="wsEjbDeploy" 
                        classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy"  
                        classpathref="was.classpath" />
               <wsEjbDeploy inputJar="target/myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                            outputJar="target/myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-DEPLOYED.jar"
                            wasHome="${my.washome}" />
            </tasks>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

The second plugin depends on the output from the first.  I have tried several different ways of doing this, but the ant plugin always runs first, even they are both in the compile phase and declared in the order that I want.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: Can you say which of the plugin ejb plugin or antrun should run first ? Cause you have defined two plugins using the same life cycle phase in such cases the order in the pom file defines the order of execution...Apart from that I have my doubts that running maven-ejb-plugin running in the compile phase is correct cause it runs by default in the package phase...

Comment: The order I have them in the pom file is the order that I expect, maven-ejb-plugin first, then maven-antrun-plugin.

Comment: My understanding is that no matter the phase in which they are defined, their order should be dictated by the order of definition.  That's what's been causing me so much grief.  I have tried defining them both in later phases, and also defining them in two different phases in the expected order, but that didn't work, either.

Comment: In general an XML file has no defined order so it's alway best to define them by using different lifecycle phases. The order of execution is defined by the life cycle. That's the way maven works. In exception having plugin executions using the same phase it is defined to use the order of their definition in the XML, but to make it sure define different phases. Furthermore related to maven-ejb-plugin cause it does not make sense to define it in the compile phase cause it's a plugin which produces and artifact which is done in the package phase...

Comment: Furthermore I have my doubts that your setup is the correct path to go...